# Difference between tests/ and inst/tests/ for R packages

Tags: r, testing, package

I'm developing a new package and I have some unit tests to write.  What's the difference between `tests/` and `inst/tests/`?  What kinds of stuff should go in each?

In particular, I see in http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2011-1/RJournal_2011-1_Wickham.pdf that Hadley recommends using `inst/tests/` "so users
also have access to them," then putting a reference in `tests/` to run them all.  But why not just put them all in `tests/`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What @hadley means is that in binary packages, `tests/` is not present; it is only in the source package. The convention is that anything in `inst/` is copied to the package top-level directory upon installation, so `inst/tests/` will be available as `/tests` in the binary and installed package directory structure.

See my **permute** package as an example. I used @hadley's **testthat** package as a learning experience and for my package tests. The package is on [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/permute/index.html). Grab the source tarball and notice that it has both `tests/` and `inst/tests/`, then grab the Windows binary and notice that only has `tests/` and that is a copy of the one from `inst/tests` in the sources.

Strictly, only `tests/` is run by `R CMD check` etc so during development and as checks in production packages you need code in `tests/` to test the package does what it claims, or other unit tests. You can of course have code in `tests/` that runs R scripts in `/inst/tests/` which actually do the tests, **and** this has the side effect of also making the test code available to package users.

The way I see things is you need at least `tests/`, whether you need `inst/tests` will depend upon how you want to develop your package and what unit testing code/packages you are using. The `inst/tests/` is something @hadley advocates but it is far from being a standard across much of CRAN.

Comment: Oh, I get it - I thought the tests/ I was seeing was actually the tests/ from the developer.  I didn't realize it was inst/tests/.  Thanks.

Comment: Well, let's take the fourth paragraph with some salt.  This really goes back to what Martin Maechler cooked up, initially for some Rmetrics packages.  `inst/tests` had been used *years* before testthat was written.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks for the history lesson; didn't know this was due to Martin. Still stand by it though; this is far from standard, even if both Martin *and* Hadley use it ;-)

Comment: They both use the same *idea*. I presume Hadley smoothed some edges; the basic use via RUnit is somewhat bare, but hey, it works...

Comment: And other than that, we both once again gave about the same answer, at about the same time. Yet another transatlantic jinx :)

Comment: It's like weather modeling - if 2 different reliable sources give the same output, it's probably correct. =)

Answer (score 5):

As 'Writing R Extensions' says, only `inst/tests` gets installed.  So only those can be used for tests for **both** the source versions of the package, and its binary (installed) form.

Otherwise `tests/` is of course there for the usual `R CMD check` tests.  Now, Martin Maechler once developed a 'hook' script from `tests/` to use `inst/tests`, and I have been using that in a few of my packages, permitting them to be invoked when a user looks at the source, as well as after the fact.  So you can in fact pivot out of the one set of tests into the other, and get the best of both worlds.

**Edit:** Here is a link to what our RProtoBuf package does to invoke inst/tests/ tests from tests/:  https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rprotobuf/blob/master/tests/runUnitTests.R  And the basic idea is due to Martin as I said.

Comment: Thanks.  I Googled for "martin maechler tests script" and didn't find what you're mentioning, do you remember where that might be?

Comment: Just like Gavin, I could refer you to my packages--besides of course the Rmetrics packages on R-Forge for which Martin did this. As for mine, RQuantLib does this, and so do the Rcpp* packages (which even produce a vignette based on the tests thanks to some nice work by Romain).

Comment: Thanks to @neal-fultz for fixing the URL above.